# Wordpress one page website load slowly using wp_is_mobile()

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm renewing the look of a website that use wordpress. For the fornt-end I'm using bootstrap 4 and I'm trying to optimize the loading time of the website. I've noticed that it's really slow when the user try to scroll and the rendering is showing some blank parts for a while after user scroll the page. It's a one page site so I don't have a page suddivision and all the contents are posts that are loaded on the `index.php` file. I've a doubt about the `wp_is_mobile()` function I'm using to detect if an user is viewing the website from desktop or mobile, I have a swiper slider loaded only on mobile and another layout structure with the same images that is loaded only on desktop. This happens with all the sections of the website and I think that is the cause of the slow rendering of the elements. I want to try using the visibility utilities of bootstrap 4 to hidden the elements that I want to display only on mobile for example:

```
<?php if( wp_is_mobile() ): ?>
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="carousel-wrapper">
  <div id="progetti-carousel" class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <?php $slider = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'slider_progetti', 'posts_per_page' => 12)); ?>
        <?php foreach($slider as $slide): ?>
          <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($slide->ID)) ?>" class="swiper-slide img-fluid"/>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

// or for desktop on the same template part:

<?php if( !wp_is_mobile() ): ?>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="card-columns">
<?php $slider = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'slider_progetti', 'posts_per_page' => 12)); ?>
<?php foreach($slider as $slide): ?>
        <div class="card">
          <a class="open-modal" data-toggle="modal" href="#zoom-image"><img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($slide->ID)) ?>" /></a>
        </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="zoom-image">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <img class="img-fluid w-100 img-zoomed" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I don't know if this can speed up the loading,I'm also worried because I don't know if the doubled queries can be a problem, for doubled queries I mean that to show the images or contents under the is mobile wordpress function, I'm using the same code that I have for desktop for that elements I want that appears on mobile in a layout and on a desktop with another one. This will break dìthe DRY principle and I know it's a bad practice. Any suggestion on how to improve the loading will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the `wp_is_mobile()` function and store the result in a variable ans reuse the variable everywhere you use `wp_is_mobile()`.

```
$is_mobile = wp_is_mobile();
```

Also, you should be using the CSS classes offered with Bootstrap for displaying/hiding elements on your layout :

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

For reference, the `wp_is_mobile()` works as follow :

```
/**
 * Test if the current browser runs on a mobile device (smart phone, tablet, etc.)
 *
 * @since 3.4.0
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function wp_is_mobile() {
    if ( empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ) {
        $is_mobile = false;
    } elseif ( strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mobile' ) !== false // many mobile devices (all iPhone, iPad, etc.)
        || strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android' ) !== false
        || strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Silk/' ) !== false
        || strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Kindle' ) !== false
        || strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'BlackBerry' ) !== false
        || strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mini' ) !== false
        || strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mobi' ) !== false ) {
            $is_mobile = true;
    } else {
        $is_mobile = false;
    }

    /**
     * Filters whether the request should be treated as coming from a mobile device or not.
     *
     * @since 4.9.0
     *
     * @param bool $is_mobile Whether the request is from a mobile device or not.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'wp_is_mobile', $is_mobile );
}
```

Comment: For now I'm not using the utils from bootstrap to hide the elements but if it combined with the wordpress function will be helpful for my scope I will give it a try!

Comment: In my opinion, it should be the role of HTML/CSS to show or hide content on your website. The `wp_is_mobile()` should be used to execute PHP functions only for mobile devices.